# error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘.’ token

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, token

I'm working with `struct`s for the first time in a long time and I am having multiple issues. I'm just trying to systematically address them but this one in particular is giving me a hard time. When I try to `make` the program, I get this:

```
`datime.c:9:23:error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘.’ token bool 
isConflict(Class.Time*, Class.Time*){`
```

and

```
`datime.c:18:21: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘.’ token bool 
isEarlier(Time.Start*, Time.Start*){`.
```

My file, `schedule.h`:

```
/*
 *      file: datime.h
 */

typedef struct
{       int hour;
        int min;
} Start;

typedef struct
{       int hour;
        int min;
} Stop;

typedef struct
{       struct Start;
        struct Stop;
} Time;

typedef struct
{       struct Time;
        int Days[7];
} Class;

bool isConflict(struct TimeA*, struct TimeB*);

bool isEarlier(struct TimeA*, struct TimeB*);
```

My file, `schedule.c`:

```
/*
 *      file: datime.c
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "datime.h"

bool isConflict(Class.Time*, Class.Time*){
        free(classA);
        free(classB);
        if ((classA.Start <= classB.Start) && (classA.Stop >= classB.Stop))
                return 1;
        else
                return 0;
}

bool isEarlier(Time.Start*, Time.Start*){
        free(classA);
        free(classB);
        if (classA.Start < classB.Start)
                return 1;
        else
                return 0;
}
```

Also, the `driver.c`, being used just to test the functions and `struct`s:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "datime.h"

main()
{
        void setClass(struct Class)
        {       struct Class EE205{
                        EE205.Time.Start.hour = 8;
                        EE205.Time.Start.min = 30;
                        EE205.Time.Stop.hour = 9;
                        EE205.Time.Stop.min = 20;

                        // Initializing array to zero
                        memset(EE205.Days, 0, 7 * sizeof(Days[0]));
                        EE205.Days[1] = 1;
                        EE205.Days[3] = 1;
                        EE205.Days[5] = 1;
                };

                struct Class EE367{
                        EE367.Time.Start.hour = 10;
                        EE367.Time.Start.min = 30;
                        EE367.Time.Stop.hour = 11;
                        EE367.Time.Stop.min = 20;

                        // Initializing array to zero
                        memset(EE367.Days, 0, 7 * sizeof(Days[0]));
                        EE367.Days[1] = 1;
                        EE367.Days[3] = 1;
                        EE367.Days[5] = 1;
                };

                struct Class EE315{
                        EE315.Time.Star.hour = 12;
                        EE315.Time.Start.min = 30;
                        EE315.Time.Stop.hour = 13;
                        EE315.Time.Stop.min = 20;

                        // Initializing array to zero
                        memset(EE315.Days, 0, 7 * sizeof(Days[0]));
                        EE315.Days[1] = 1;
                        EE315.Days[3] = 1;
                        EE315.Days[5] = 1;
                };
        if(isConflict(EE315, EE367))
                printf("Scheduling conflict! EE315 and EE367 conflict.");
        if(isConflict(EE315, EE205))
                printf("Scheduling conflict! EE315 and EE205 conflict.");
        if(isConflict(EE205, EE367))
                printf("Scheduling conflict! EE205 and EE367 conflict.");

}
```

There are a lot of errors, but these errors are the two that I cannot move passed for whatever reason. Thanks in advance.

- Allen

Comment: `bool isConflict(Class.Time* ct1, Class.Time* ct2)`

Comment: I forgot to instantiate that at all, thanks.

Comment: Also, unless you declared a "bool" type, C doesn't have this type.
EDIT : Sorry I didn't see the include

Comment: Doesn't the function/method definition need to know whats the name of the parameter? So it can use the identifier to refer to it?

Comment: @Cyril Fougeray: not true. C has type _Bool, and some platforms do typedef to bool if it is pure C

Comment: `bool isConflict(Time *A, Time *B);

bool isEarlier(Time *A, Time *B);`

Comment: Please post less code.

Comment: I propose to get this book: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language and read!

Comment: Your code is all meaningless nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't any legal C syntax.

```
 bool isConflict(Class.Time*, Class.Time*)
```

(Actually almost nothing of the code is valid. I suggest you start learning structs and pointers with a much smaller example/program)

You'll have to declare it as e.g.

```
bool isConflict(Class* classA, Class *classB){
```

The body is quite strange too, I cannot really figure out what you intend to do:

```
        free(classA); <--- free() classA/classB, but 2 lines down you try to access them ?
        free(classB);

       // if ((classA.Start <= classB.Start) && (classA.Stop >= classB.Stop))
        //since classA/classB are pointers you need -> to access their members:
        // You also need to compare the members of Time, you can't compare structs
        // in C, e.g. to check the hours:
         if ((classA->Start.hour <= classB->Start.hour) && 
             (classA->Stop.hour >= classB->Stop.hour))
                return 1;
        else
                return 0;
}
```

Your isEearlier function has the same problem.

```
main()
{
       //you can't declare a function within another function like this.
       //what is the purpose of the setClass function ? There is no code that calls this function
       //you also need to give names to your function parameters, if you want a pointer, it'd be
       //void setClass(struct Class *my_class)

        void setClass(struct Class)
        {
```

Your `Time` struct is wrong, you havn't given any variable names to the members, it should be:

```
typedef struct
{       Start Start;
        Stop Stop;
} Time;
```

(However, your `struct Start` and `struct Stop` are identical, there's no need to create 2 struct definitions for both)

The initializers for your struct is wrong:

```
struct Class EE205{
    EE205.Time.Start.hour = 8;
    EE205.Time.Start.min = 30;
    EE205.Time.Stop.hour = 9;
    EE205.Time.Stop.min = 20;
};
```

Note that you say `struct Class`, but nowhere have you defined a `struct Class`. You have a typedef
to a struct, the typedef is just called `Class`, so the compiler will not know about `struct Class`, it only knows about `Class`

You can set the members like:

```
Class EE205;
EE205.Time.Start.hour = 8;
EE205.Time.Start.min = 30;
EE205.Time.Stop.hour = 9;
EE205.Time.Stop.min = 20;
// Initializing array to zero
memset(EE205.Days, 0, 7);
EE205.Days[1] = 1;
EE205.Days[3] = 1;
EE205.Days[5] = 1;
```

Or initialize it:

```
Class EE205 = {
  {
    {8, 30},
    {9,20}
  },
  {0,1,0,1,0,1}
};
```

Comment: Since it's `typedef struct { ... } Start`, shouldn't it be just `Start Start` (or perhaps better - `Start start`), not `struct Start Start`?

Comment: @Dukeling, I corrected that. Using lower case for the variable name would be much better, but I wanted to avoid changing too much.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was only asking for the help with the one particular issue. But I guess I set myself up for that when I posted so much bad code. Regardless, I'm grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely wrong, you cannot use structure type as structure members.

```
/* 2 structures type doing the same thing? */
typedef struct
{       int hour;
        int min;
} Start;

typedef struct
{       int hour;
        int min;
} Stop;

typedef struct
{       struct Start; /* variable name missing */
        struct Stop;
} Time;

typedef struct
{       struct Time;
        int Days[7];
} Class;

bool isConflict(struct TimeA*, struct TimeB*); /* makes no sense */

bool isEarlier(struct TimeA*, struct TimeB*);
```

Let's rewrite it:

```
/* Replaced Start/Stop with time */
typedef struct
{       int hour;
        int min;
} Time;

/*
    Added member names.
    Removed struct because using typedef for Time
*/
typedef struct
{       Time start;
        Time stop;
} TimeSpan;

typedef struct
{       TimeSpan timeSpan;
        int Days[7];
} Class;

/*
    First type, then variable name for each parameter.
    Also removed the invalid struct marker.
*/
bool isConflict(Time * a, Time * b);

bool isEarlier(Time * a, Time * b);
```

This does't fix the problems with the actual code yet, but now you should 
at least have your type declarations right.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors.

- You are using `typedef` so there is not need to use `struct` after
- You just enter the type in the `struct` and you forgot the `name`
- Same in the function declaration

Here is your header file:

```
/*
 *      file: datime.h
 */

typedef struct
{       int hour;
        int min;
} Start;

typedef struct
{       int hour;
        int min;
} Stop;

typedef struct
{       Start start;
        Stop stop;
} Time;

typedef struct
{       Time time;
        int days[7];
} Class;

bool isConflict(Time *timeA, Time *timeB);

bool isEarlier(Time *timeA, Time *timeB);
```

In your source file there is mistakes too:

- You are using `struct` pointer so to acces member you have to use `->` and not `.`
- You are using `bool` with `<stdbool.h>` so you should return `true` or `false`
- You can't `free` things that you will access later (or you will have a segmentation fault)

Here is your source file:

```
/*
 *      file: datime.c
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "datime.h"

bool isConflict(Time *timeA, Time *timeB) {
        if ((timeA->start <= timeB->start) && (timeA->stop >= timeB->stop))
                return true;
        else
                return false;
}

bool isEarlier(Time *timeA, Time *timeB) {
        if (timeA->start < timeB->start)
                return true;
        else
                return false;
}
```

There is also a lot of mistakes in your main. I let you see the other responses ....